# How to work with astronomical measurements in blender

Tags: 3d-view, measurement

I am trying to make a really big sphere (a planet) in blender. But it seems like my view of it is cut off in the viewport. This also results in malfunctions when I export it into FBX.

I tried tweaking clip start and clip end values. Especially, I set the clip end to a very high number (10000 km). My scene also uses kilometers as the length type. But for some reason, when I try to add a 1500km radius sphere into my scene, I can't see all my sphere as it is cut off when I try to zoom out of the scene.

I use Blender 2.92. Here is the project file that I am working with https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dsGHHenIWn3NNIuXKEm-w87Xy_LmRhNu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Consider choosing an arbitrary scale, for example  1 blender unit = 1000 km.  Blender does not work well with large numbers.

Comment: Could you explain in detail how do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878586/huge-scale-scenes-in-blender